# Is every Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ somewhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis

An outline of the (probably incorrect) proof:

> Let $H$ be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. For
> contradiction, assume that $H$ is nowhere dense. Then for each
> interval $I_n = (n, n+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have $\overline{I_n
>  \cap H} \neq I_n$. This implies that $I_n$ contains countably many points
> of  $H$, which then implies that $H$ is countable, a contradiction.

But I'm not sure about how to prove that $\overline{I_n
\cap H} \neq I_n$ implies that $H \cap I_n$ is at most countable (or even if it's true).

Because if $I_n \cap H$ were uncountable, then $I_n \cap H$ has uncountably many accumulation points in $I_n$. But does it then imply that $H$ is dense in $I_n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true.  For instance, let $K$ be the set of numbers in $[0,1/2]$ that have a base $3$ expansion using only the digits $0$ and $1$.  This set is nowhere dense (it is just the usual Cantor set scaled down by a factor of $2$).  Every element of $[0,1]$ can be written as a sum of two elements of $K$ (proof: elements of $K$ can be added in base $3$ digit-by-digit with no carrying, so you just need to observe that every possible base $3$ digit can be written as a sum of two digits that are either $0$ or $1$).  It follows that $K$ spans all of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  So, there exists a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is contained in $K$ and thus nowhere dense.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!